# Optional property in class

Tags: swift, option-type

I just started learning Swift.
"addlist" method doesn't add value to array? Why? Help me to understand.

```
var arrayList: [String]?

func addlist(list: String) {
    if let _ = arrayList?.firstIndex(of: list) {
        print("Already exists")
    } else {
        arrayList?.append(list)
    }
}

addlist(list: "1")
arrayList?.count // result nil
```

Comment: You never initialized the array. It's `nil`. For array, usually, no need to make them optional, init them as empty: `var arrayList: [String]?` => `var arrayList: [String] = [String]()`, or `var arrayList: [String] = []`

Comment: Change your array declaration to non optional. Your optional chaining is doing exactly what you asked. It is silently failing.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax

`var?.function()` is known as "optional chaining." It tells the compiler "if the variable (which is an Optional) contains nil, stop. If it is not nil, call the function on that object.

If you define an array `arrayList` as type `[String]?` that creates an Optional variable `arrayList` that **can** contain an array of Strings, or it could be nil. It will start out as nil and stay that way until you save an array into it.

You never store an array in `arrayList`, so it's always nil.

Thus your optional chaining always fails to do anything.

As others said in comments, define your `arrayList` variable to contain an empty array:

```
var arrayList = [String]()
```

Then it will never be nil, and you will always be able to add items to it without using Optional chaining.